# Creating a hyperlink within a table cell

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm attempting to creating a hyperlink within a cell of a table, but currently the hyperlink just displays as text within the table.  Looking at the console I can see `linkElement` is getting created properly as:

```
<a href="some url">text</a>
```

My JS code

```
//Creating the table
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
//creating URL elements 
linkElement = document.createElement("a");
linkElement.setAttribute("href", url);
var linkText = document.createTextNode(url);
linkElement.append(linkText);
console.log(linkElement)
cell1.innerHTML = linkElement;
cell2.innerHTML = appVersion;
```

My HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out using `cell1.innerHTML=  '<a href="'+url+'">'+linkElement+'</a>';`

Answer (score 0):

Use `cell1.append(linkElement)`, `cell1.innerHTML` is meant to be use when providing the HTML as string not an object.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, now I just have `cell2.innerHTML = appVersion;`  populating.